# Jenkins in Docker container (run docker pipeline)

Tags: docker, jenkins

I want to run Jenkins in Docker container. Everything is OK. I can run it like this: `docker run -d --name jenkins -t -i -p 49001:8080 jenkins` I can also add persistent storage. The problem came when I created a pipeline can has to execute `docker` commands (`build` and `push`). First the error was that docker wasn't installed on the system. Yes, expected. Then I started searching and found out how I can run docker in container (passing 2 persistent volumes): `docker run ... -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -p 49001:8080 jenkins`

This runs, but with some exceptions. There is `docker` command in the container but when I try to run it, it throws an exception: `docker: error while loading shared libraries: libltdl.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

How can I fix this problem? What is the correct way for installing Jenkins in Docker and run Docker in it? I think there are 2 ways:

1. The one that I am doing - use the sockets
2. I can expose the docker api that allows connections and running commands

Actually is it worth running Jenkins in Docker? I tried to install the missing lib manually from the `apt-get` It works but I know that it's not the correct way..

Comment: Would https://www.vip-consult.solutions/post/easy-docker-swarm-jenkins-continuous-deployment-at-scale#content help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to install `libltdl-dev` in order to get everything working correctly. Create a `Dockerfile` that looks like this:

```
FROM jenkins:latest

USER root
RUN apt-get update \
      && apt-get upgrade -y \
      && apt-get install -y sudo libltdl-dev \
      && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

USER jenkins
# Here you can install some Jenkins plugins if you want
```

Comment: i created a simple workaround image
https://hub.docker.com/r/jesusperales/jenkins-docker-run-inside/

Comment: Thanks for the image

Comment: @kirpt what's the `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` for?

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple update from @Israel Perales docker image, bcz above one is does not work anymore

```
   FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts


    USER root
    RUN apt-get update \
          && apt-get upgrade -y \
          && apt-get install -y sudo libltdl-dev libnss3 \
          && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    RUN echo "jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

    USER jenkins
```

Build the docker image and run as below:

```
$ docker build -t docIndoc .

$ docker run --name jenkins -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):$(which docker) docIndoc

$ docker exec -it jenkins /bin/bash
```